# Zooming the whole screen with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, zooming, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I was trying to add a pinch gesture zoom-in zoom-out feature to a UITextView and then I decided that adding a pinch gesture which zooms the whole screen, covering the whole view hierarchy is a better and more general solution. But I am confused about how to do it: Should I change the frame sizes of all UIView objects or should I somehow scale them? What is the most correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your views in a `UIScrollView` and then return the view in this delegate method of `UIScrollView`

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I have an another scrollview inside this root scrollview? Wouldn't it lead to a confusion about which scroll view is going to get scrolled?

Comment: You can give tags to UIScrollView and then this tag in this delegate method.